# Can linearization of a function around $x=0$ show whether first derivative is positive or negative?

Tags: linear-algebra, control-theory

As title says, can linearization of a function $f(x)$ (by the method of taylor series around $x=0$) show whether first derivative of the function ($df/dx$) is positive or negative at $x=0$?

And.. the answer is obvious, meh.

Comment: Yes. Linearization has negative slope if and only if derivative is negative..

Comment: Oh. I just realized that I should have phrased the question differently... I wasn't intending to write like that.. But anyway. I'll ask a separate question then. Thanks everyone.

Comment: It is a little more complicated (Thinking that we do not know what $f(x)$ is, but knows the value of taylor series and so on.. then finding out..) But I realized I phrased my question in a wrong direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  The taylor series of $f$ centered at zero begins:
$$f(0) + f'(0)x + \cdots$$
so if you know the taylor series at zero then you know the first derivative at zero.